# Error when using Drawer Navigation for React Navigation for Web

Tags: react-native, babeljs, navigation-drawer, react-native-web, react-native-reanimated

I had this error only with Drawer Navigation in Web.

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-reanimated/lib/createAnimatedComponent.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\lib\createAnimatedComponent.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (448:9):

  446 |       });
  447 |       return (
> 448 |         <Component {...props} ref={this._setComponentRef} {...platformProps} />
      |         ^
  449 |       );
  450 |     }
  451 |   }

Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
    at Parser._raise (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:569:17)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:562:17)
    at Parser.expectOnePlugin (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3626:18)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12055:18)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11654:23)
    at Parser.parseUpdate (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11634:21)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11609:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11421:61)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11428:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11398:23)


ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-reanimated/lib/reanimated1/Transitioning.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\lib\reanimated1\Transitioning.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (36:7):

  34 |   return (props) => {
  35 |     return (
> 36 |       <TransitioningContext.Consumer>
     |       ^
  37 |         {(context) => <Comp context={context} {...props} />}
  38 |       </TransitioningContext.Consumer>
  39 |     );

Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
    at Parser._raise (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:569:17)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:562:17)
    at Parser.expectOnePlugin (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3626:18)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12055:18)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11654:23)
    at Parser.parseUpdate (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11634:21)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11609:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11421:61)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11428:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11398:23)


ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-screens/src/screens.web.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\react-native-screens\src\screens.web.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (105:12):

  103 |
  104 |   render() {
> 105 |     return <Animated.View {...this.props} ref={this._setRef} />;
      |            ^
  106 |   }
  107 | }
  108 |

Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://git.io/vb4yA) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
    at Parser._raise (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:569:17)
    at Parser.raiseWithData (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:562:17)
    at Parser.expectOnePlugin (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3626:18)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12055:18)
    at Parser.parseExprSubscripts (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11654:23)
    at Parser.parseUpdate (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11634:21)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnary (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11609:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeUnaryOrPrivate (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11421:61)
    at Parser.parseExprOps (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11428:23)
    at Parser.parseMaybeConditional (C:\Users\weve\Documents\Projetos\ReactNative\Linguis\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11398:23)
```

Well I created a simple class and include my Drawer navigation (Note this issues happened only with drawer, because with @react-navigation/native-stack this is works)

Rn.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Message from "./Message.web";
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MyDrawer() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Message" component={Message} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

function Rn() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyDrawer />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default Rn;
```

I call this in App.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
enableScreens();
import React from 'react';
import {enableScreens} from 'react-native-screens';

import RouteWeb from './components/web/Rn';
import RouteNative from './components/native/Route.native';
import { Platform} from "react-native";

const App = () => {  
  return Platform.OS == "web" ? <RouteWeb/> : <RouteNative />
};

export default App;
```

Message.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

const Message = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Message Web</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Message;
```

My dependences in package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^2.1.0",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "npm": "^8.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.64.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^1.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.15.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.0-beta.5"
  }
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = { 
presets: ["@babel/preset-react"],
//I tried to use this plugins below but doesn't work
//  plugins: ["@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx", "react-native-reanimated/plugin"]
}
```

According to error I tried to include @babel/preset-react and after @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx in babel.config.js and didn't work.

I appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue changing version following this topic https://githubmate.com/repo/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9758
and add this metro-transform-worker on package.json.

The final result was

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^2.1.0",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "metro-transform-worker": "^0.66.2",
    "npm": "^8.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "^0.64.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.9",
    "react-native-reanimated": "1.13.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.15.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.0-beta.5"
  },
```

Comment: But a new problem happened, when the hamburguer ícone has clicked the sidebar not open.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in babel.config.js

plugins: ["@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx", "react-native-reanimated/plugin"],

And then add the following line in package.json

"resolutions": {
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.9.1"
},